# Non reflexive space not satisfying the following property.

Tags: normed-spaces, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a normed space. If $X$ is reflexive, one can show that

$l\in X' \implies  \exists x\in X : ||x|| = 1 \ \  \land \ \ l(x) = ||l||$

#### Proof of above statement

Given a normed space $X$, we know the following is true:

$$ x\in X \implies \exists l \in X': ||l||=1 \ \land \ l(x)=||x||$$

Applying the theorem on $X'$, we get:

$$ l\in X' \implies \exists L \in X'': ||L||=1 \ \land \ L(l)=||l||$$

$X$ being reflexive means that the canonical map $T : X \to X''$ is a bijective isometry  where:
$$Tx(l) = l(x)$$

Hence we know that $||Tx|| = ||x||$ and that $T^{-1}$ exists. Now pick $l \in X'$. Hence $\exists L\in X''$ such that $||L||= 1$ and $L(l) = ||l||$. Let $x = T^{-1}L$, i.e., $Tx = L$. Then

$$||x|| = ||Tx|| = ||L|| = 1$$

and
$$l(x) = Tx(l) = L(l) = ||l||$$

which proves the assertion.

#### Original question

I'm trying to find an example of a non reflexive space that does not satisfy the property above. Any ideas?

#### Answer

From the hint I got in the comments, this is an example.

Let $X = \{x\in C([0,1]\ |\   x(0)=0)\}$ and $l:X\to\mathbb{R},\ l(x) = \int\limits_0^1x(t)dt$.

Then, $|l(x)| \le 1$ if $||x|| = 1$. On the other hand, we can easily construct a sequence $x_n$ such that $l(x_n) \to 1$, hence $||l|| = 1$. But $\not\exists x\in X: ||x||=1 \ \land l(x) = 1$. This is because $||x|| = 1$ and $x(0) = 0$ implies that $l(x) < 0$.

Comment: $X=\{f \in C[0,1]: f(0)=0\}$, $l (f)=\int_0^{1} f(x)dx$. (Check that $\|l\|=1$)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have provided an example, using your hint. I really appreciate that your fast responses, my best virtual teacher :)

Comment: What about a triangle with area 1? The function is positive, though.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh What about the triangle? I do not get your point sorry.

Comment: @JustANoob: I am sorry, I thought something different and commented. Please ignore the comment.

Comment: @JustANoob Could you briefly tell how can you prove the result in a reflexive space?

Comment: @Eparoh, Full proof is provided, see edit.

Comment: @JustANoob Thanks! I have forgotten so many consequences oh Hanh-Banach :')